# Cambiar el id de un video Youtube en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, youtube

Estoy tratando de cambiar el id de un video en my html, que se encuentra en otro archivo javascript, en donde la API de youtube es creada. También leo los id's de un archico JSON.

HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
   <div id="player">
      <script>
         function routes(arr) {
            var out = "";
            var a = 3;
            for(i = 2; i<a; i++) {
               out = arr[i].videoID;
               player.loadVideoById("out");
            }           
      </script>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

 var player;
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   player = new YT.Player('player', {
     playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 2 },
     height: '390',
     width: '640',
     //videoId: 'xck9LoSvDvc',
     events: {
       'onReady': onPlayerReady,
     }
   });
 }
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error :

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input*

en la linea;

```
player.loadVideoById("out");
```

podrian ayudarme por favor!

muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que el método `loadVideoById()` debe recibir el id  del videp y tu estas agregando un string "out" lo cual es incorrecto, debe ser:

```
 out = arr[i].videoID;
 player.loadVideoById(out);
```

además también falta un } para cerrar tu función.

```
<script>
         function routes(arr) {
            var out = "";
            var a = 3;
            for(i = 2; i<a; i++) {
               out = arr[i].videoID;
               player.loadVideoById(out);
            }    
         }       
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Falta la última llave `}` en el script

```
  <script>
     function routes(arr) {
        var out = "";
        var a = 3;
        for(i = 2; i<a; i++) {
           out = arr[i].videoID;
           player.loadVideoById("out");
        }           
     } // falta
  </script>
```